# Location of tax calculation in source for Shopping Cart

Tags: php, magento

can someone please tell me where the calculation of the amount of tax included in the total price of products is in Magento?

Im looking at /app/code/core/Mage/Tax but don't know where to look at.

Working with discounts calculates the tax wrong in version 1.4.0 and I desperately need help fixing this.

Sadly the original magento forum is kind of abandoned...

Greetz
Spanky

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change the way tax is applied to discounted orders in the configuration section of your admin backend. There are options like "apply tax after discount" etc.

Comment: thx, I know and I tried "before tax" and "after tax" one recalculates the price which is wrong and the other one doesn't calculate the tax on the discount price but on the original one. So something is messed up.